# remove part of string and return new string php

Tags: php

let's say that I have strings like these:

```
$str1 = '7.5.4';
$str2 = '7.19.41';
```

How do I remove the last few characters of each string starting from the last dot so that my strings become:

```
$str1 = '7.5';
$str2 = '7.19';
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you even tried anything?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
   $str1 = substr( $str1, 0, strrpos( $str1, '.' ) );
```

**Update**

In your particular case, you can also simply use [`floatval`](https://www.php.net/floatval)

```
$str1 = '7.5.4';
$str2 = '7.19.41';

echo floatval($str1) . "\n";
echo floatval($str2) . "\n";
```

Note that if terminating zeros count, you would need to combine it with [`number_format`](https://www.php.net/number_format) or [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/sprintf)

```
$str1 = '7.50.4';
$str2 = '7.10.41';

echo number_format(floatval($str1), 2, '.', '') . "\n";
echo sprintf('%0.2f', floatval($str2));
```

If this is the case, you don't really gain anything over the initial solution and you're also tied to a specific precision (`'7.190.41'` would still yield `7.19`, and `'7.191'` would also yield `7.19`). But, if you don't care about terminating zeros it's a win.

Comment: This is the best way. Here's a regex way, just in case: `echo preg_replace("/(.*)(\.[^.]+)/", "$1", $str);`